# Map a field from the opportunity to the DocuSign Envelope when sending

Tags: docusign

We have a date on the opportunity that is "Proposal Valid Until" and the rep adds a date.  We need to map that to be the expiration (in days?) to the envelope when the users creates and envelope sending the DS from the opportunity.

[image: Envelope Expiration]

Any good ideas on how to map that date field (or using another field with a formula to convert to days) then adding that to the envelope expiration on creation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, can add

```
// Reminder and Expiration Settings
RES = '0,0,0,1,{!Opportunity.Default_Expiration_Days__c},2'; //Ex: '0,1,2,0,120,3'
```

To the custom DS button JS and it sets it as the default (given default expiration days = formula from the valid until date).